# How to Overclock my old PC's(Pentium 4) processor using Ubuntu?

Tags: overclocking

I am new in **Overclocking** stuff. I am using an old gen. PC with 32-bit Pentium 4 with 3.0 GHz speed with Ubuntu 14.04 installed on it. I want to improve my CPU performance because it is really really slow.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You overclock CPU is bios, if it supports it, not in an OS.

Comment: And Also Ubuntu is too heave for that CPU. Try Lubuntu.

Comment: you can also use Xubuntu, I run Ubuntu 14.04 on the same processor like yours with no big issues but it requires tweaks to be applied to make it faster, use unity-tweak-tool, ubuntu-tweak-tool, tun off system update manager to push/check for updates do it with terminal it will save you resources. An I wouldn't recommend you to overclock it more.